# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests, python-3.6

I have installed the pip3 as well as the *requests* package on my pc. Even then, on running the command **import requests** on my shell, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I have to manually copy all the packages to my working directory to tackle this exception.

I am working with Windows 10, using a Python 3.6.1 shell.

Comment: Are you working with windows?

Comment: You might have several python versions installed?

Comment: yes @doratheexplorer0911

Comment: What shell are you using to run it - cmd?

Comment: YES i am working with windows 10 @doratheexplorer0911

Comment: using python 3.6.1 shell @doratheexplorer0911

Comment: yes i do @Grimmy

Comment: Then you are probably using the wrong python executable. There is not enough info in your question to know. How was the code executed?

Comment: Try in same shell `import pip` and then `pip.main (['install', 'requests'])`

Comment: The code got executed when i manually move all the packages that got installed when i installed pip3 and requests to my current working directory @Grimmy

Comment: Not working @Zydnar

Comment: Can you be more specific what isn't working now? Command or your application?

Comment: @Jaskunwarsingh Let me make this easier. Include everything you typed in the terminal before this error happened.

Answer (score 18):

Find were your Python interpreter is installed and find the *"Scripts"* directory. Open [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), go to this folder and type `pip install requests`.

For me it was like below:

```
cd C:\Users\myLocalUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 2):

In [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) you should:

1. Go back to base configuration in menu *"File"* → *"Settings"* → *"Python Interpreter"* (it is the path that ends with "...\python.exe")
2. Click on the plus and install this module by typing name in search field.
3. Choose this configuration and run it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For listing installed modules for *Python 3*:

```
sudo pip3 list
```

For installing the `request` module for *Python 3*:

```
sudo pip3 install requests
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Requests module should have a version that starts with 2.

Not correct

```
pip3 list
```

Output:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
requestes       0.0.1
```

I installed this and installed using

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Later:

```
cd C:\python\Scripts
pip list
```

Output:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ---------

certifi         2021.5.30

chardet         4.0.0

idna            2.10

pip             21.1.3

**requests        2.25.1**

urllib3         1.26.6
```

Comment: *requestes* vs. *requests*: Are you sure it is not some kind of [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting)?

Comment: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&amp;lq=1#comment134785674_76440240) e.g. *[Several malicious typosquatted Python libraries found on PyPI repository](https://thehackernews.com/2021/07/several-malicious-typosquatted-python.html)*. That is, '`requests`' (the real library) vs. '`request`' (The malicious one. Without "s")

Answer (score 0):

Activate a virtual environment:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

Install the dependencies:

```
pip install request
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been tackling this issue for two hours now, and this solution did it!

Find your Python installation location and, specifically, the Scripts directory. Open `cmd`, and run the following:

```
cd C:\Users\<myLocalUserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used the package manager within my IDE ([PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) in this case) to see if 'request' was installed. Once I did that, then the error went away.

I also tried `pip install`, but I suspect I have multiple Python installations on the system and pip didn't install to the correct Python interpreter. This is why others are suggesting to install from a specific Python installation.

In Linux or Mac, you can run 'which python' for additional clues.

Comment: Re *"request"* (without "`s`"): That is probably why [the typosquatting attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&amp;lq=1#comment134785674_76440240) was so successful.